# configuring telegraf for TLS client authentication/authorization

Tags: ssl, telegraf, tls1.3

I am using telegraf for collecting telemetry data from mimic server. Internally its using gNMI.

I need to enable TLS client authentication/authorization so that only valid devices can send telemetry data to server.

I am not sure how this is exactly done, and couldn't find any official documentation for same.

Any inputs on it are appreciated.